# How to Place comments right under the comment box in a guestbook made in html+php+mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have one guestbook application where an user can enter his name, email and message and then it's stored on a database which I open it afterwards through a php file to view the comments.

My question is: How can I add those comments (when the user clicks submit buttoN) directly to the html page under the comment box in descending order by post hour/date? ( i don't need the date/hour to be displayed, I just want the comments to be placed consecutively)

I use guestbook.php to take the data from db and display it when a user clicks on it(it's a button on my index.html page named Guestbook). Here is the code for Guestbook.php:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; //Add your SQL Server host here
$user="db1"; //SQL Username
$pass="test123"; //SQL Password
$dbname="db1"; //SQL Database Name
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name,message FROM db1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
<h3><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h3>
<p><?php echo $row['message']; ?></p>
<?php } 
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And I'll show u the part of my index.html code(the body) which contains the name, email, message box, security check box and the footer:

```
<ul id="mainMenu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="guestbook.php" id="active">Guestbook</a></li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</div>
<div id="content">

<h2>Sign to the Guest Book </h2>
    <form name="guest" method="post" action="addcomment.php" onsubmit="return Validate();">
        <span>Name:</span>    <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
        <span>Email:</span> <input type="text" name="email"/><br />
        <p>Message:</p> <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50"> </textarea> <br />
        <p>5+5 = ? (in letters):</p> <input type="text" name="res"> </textarea> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Sign this in the Book" />
  </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<hr/>
<p>Thank you for the visit! </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, i'm thinking that somehow it's possible to replace the footer with a section which will contain the comments underneath...but idk how to take those comments from db and place them there using html code

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, what you want to do is:

1. Rename your `index.html` to `index.php`
2. Add `<?php include ("guestbook.php"); ?>` to the file where you want the entries to appear.

Comment: Ok, now I have another question. The comments are added descending but I want them to be added ascending, meaning that the last comment added to be the first... How can I do that? Is there also a simple way to do it?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted :) You can add "DESC" and "ORDER BY" to your query: `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name,message FROM db1 ORDER BY id DESC");` Note that you need to specify a field for ordering, so that would be the ID if it auto-increments.

Comment: I accepted it, also voted it but didn`t count. maybe beacuse i have poor reputation in here..Yes I/ve marked the A.I. when made the primary key in SQL. So it works, the last comment comes the first. Thanx

Comment: And now if i'm still buzzing your head here for tonight, I have one and last question: when i click submit, and echo message appears with "values stored in the database", but that message appears in another page: my addcomment.php opens displaying that echo message and if I wanna come back to the index.html page I have to hit backspace. Is it possible to somehow stay on the index.html page when I click submit? Or at least make a button "Get back" in the addcomment.php?

Comment: Here is my addcomment.php last part of the code: 
 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 else
  echo "Values Stored in the Database!";
 mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: To stay on the same page, use AJAX in JavaScript (just give it a Google Search, you will quickly find information on that, it'd be too much for a comment in here). To add a button, use this: `echo 'Values stored in the Database! <a href="/">Go back</a>';`

Comment: Thank you, i'll give it a try. Long Live the Cats!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.prepend()` function:

```
var information = ""; // The information from the form.
$("#footer").prepend(information);
```